# HTML5 Python Download Link doesn't work?

Tags: python, html, file, download

I went online trying to find out how to use the download attribute in HTML5. I was told to use this code:

```
<a href="file.*" download="filename">Click here!</a>
```

I wanted to add a download link where a `.py` file is downloaded to run (I have noted about having to install Python), but I just get an error saying that the webpage can't be found.

I'm guessing that the website is assuming that it is meant to be used as a webpage file, but I don't get why it won't be recognised since the filename is correct and the file is there.

Any advice on making the `.py` file a downloadable via link?

I am using the Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: "I was told to use this code" told by whom exactly?

Comment: @PeeHaa The download attribute actually is supported in Edge 13 http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: Also http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Yes. But that doesn't answer my question at all :P As in is that `*` actually suppose to work??

Comment: @PeeHaa ah yeah it’s not supposed to work. See my answer. I guess the OP thought that the presence of the download attribute somehow makes wildcards be allowed in URLs.

Comment: That wildcard was there as an example in the syntax. Im not dumb enough to actually put that in my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the URL you are using in the `href` attribute. It has nothing to do with the `download` attribute.

In your example:

**wrong way to do it**

```
<a href="file.*" download="filename">Click here!</a>
```

…you’re telling your browser to request a file literally named `file.*`.

But you can’t put wildcards in Web URLs. So your browser is requesting a file literally named `file.*` and the Web server is not finding such as file (because it doesn’t exist). Hence the “webpage can't be found” message you’re seeing.

Here’s an example of using the `download` attribute as it was intended:

**right way to do it**

```
<a href="/some/path/somefilename.py" download="file-to-save-as.py">Click here!</a>
```

For more info, see:

- the [details about the `download` attribute at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download),: which say this:

  > This attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the
  >   hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource so that **when the user
  >   clicks on the link they will be prompted to save it as a local file**.
  >   If the attribute has a value, the value will be used as the **pre-filled
  >   file name in the Save prompt that opens when the user clicks on the
  >   link** (the user can change the name before actually saving the file of
  >   course).
- the actual [definition of the `download` attribute in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-hyperlink-download), which say this:

  > The download attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends
  >   the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource. The attribute may
  >   have a value; the value, if any, specifies the default file name that
  >   the author recommends for use in labeling the resource in a local file
  >   system.

Comment: That was just what the syntax was. What I put in the code was:    <a href="python.py" download="Python">Click here!</a> The python.py is in the root directory

Comment: Yeah, so that will work except you have the value of the download attribute wrong. It should just also be `python.py`; download="python.py`. I’ll update my answer.

Comment: So it still needs to end in .py? Huh! And does the href need to be equal to the full computer directory? Because it is in the root folder with the main files.

Comment: If your file is literally named `python.py` and is in the same directory that contains the page that has that `<a href>` in it, then just do this:  `<a href="python.py" download="python.py">Click here!</a>`. If the file is instead in the root directory of the site, then instead do `<a href="/python.py" download="python.py">Click here!</a>`. The href value just still needs to be a real URL to a real file on the server. The download attribute doesn’t change that requirement.

Comment: This isnt a public website, just some files on my desktop. Does the same thing apply?

Comment: Ok, so I just tried what you said, and i guess it did work just not in the way I wanted it to. It opened the file and used it like a txt file. It just displayed the code. I need it to download so that you can click the download and open the program. Is this really possible? I have python installed.

Comment: Ah. Well, having a file actually be automatically run one you receive it is outside of the scope of the the `download` attribute. But for that I think you’d normally want to start by making sure that in the response the file’s being sent with the right MIME media type. But there is no standard media type for python files. So it’s pretty much always going to download as plain text.

Comment: I guess there’s some way that you, as a user, can configure your browser to tell it, “When I download a file with a `.py` filename, I want you to go ahead and automatically run it as an executable file.” But there’s certainly no way that you, as a Web developer, can in your Web page say “Make sure this Python script automatically executes any time any users click on this link.” For sort of obvious reasons.